# echo for Print output

Tags: cat, echo

I want to use the `echo` command to show this output:

```
10 item in File
```

but seems that the below command does not work:

```
echo "$('cat file.txt | wc -l ') items in File"
```

Comment: What does it print, and why is that wrong?

Comment: Rewrite to: echo "$(cat file.txt | wc -l) items in File" ... it's because you are looking for a command defined as that inside the quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command is:

```
echo "$(wc -l < file.txt) items in File"
```

Note the quotes, for example, by doing:

```
$('du / -h | sort -h')
```

You are telling to the shell "hey, execute 'du / -h | sort -h'", and bash will reply, "oh no, I don't know what is 'du / -h | sort -h' is". I am a not 100% sure but I think that when you quote something you escape special characters, like '|'.

The solution for the above example is remove the quotes.

```
$(du / -h | sort -h)
```

The output of your command already tells what is going on:

```
zsh: command not found: cat file.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: Also, `$( wc -l <file.txt )`, to remove useless use of `cat`.